# Refreshing BindingSource after insert (Linq To SQL)

Tags: winforms, linq-to-sql, bindingsource

I have a grid bound to a `BindingSource` which is bound to `DataContext` table, like this:

```
myBindingSource.DataSource = myDataContext.MyTable;
myGrid.DataSource = myBindingSource;
```

I couldn't refresh `BindingSource` after insert. This didn't work:

```
myDataContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, myBindingSource);
myBindingSource.ResetBinding(false);
```

Neither this:

```
myDataContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, myDataContext.MyTable);
myBindingSource.ResetBinding(false);
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem but not in a way I wanted.

Turns out that DataContext and Linq To SQL is best for unit-of-work operations. Means you create a DataContext, get your job done, discard it. If you need another operation, create another one.

For this problem only thing I had to do was recreate my DataContext like this.dx = new MyDataContext();. If you don't do this you always get stale/cached data. From what I've read from various blog/forum posts that DataContext is lightweight and doing this A-OK. This was the only way I've found after searching for a day.

Answer (score 1):

And finally one more working solution.

This solution works fine and do not require recreating DataContext.

1. **You need to reset internal Table cache.**
   for this you need change private property cachedList of Table using reflection.

You can use following utility code:

```
    public static class LinqDataTableExtension
    {
        public static void ResetTableCache(this ITable table)
        {
            table.InternalSetNonPublicFieldValue("cachedList", null);
        }

        public static void ResetTableCache(this IListSource source)
        {
            source.InternalSetNonPublicFieldValue("cachedList", null);
        }

        public static void InternalSetNonPublicFieldValue(this object entity, string propertyName, object value)
        {
            if (entity == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyName");

            var type = entity.GetType();
            var prop = type.GetField(propertyName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            if (prop != null)
                prop.SetValue(entity, value);
// add any exception code here if property was not found :)
        }
    }
```

using something like:

```
   var dSource = Db.GetTable(...)
   dSource.ResetTableCache();
```

2. **You need to reset your BindingSource** using something like:

   _BindingSource.DataSource = new List();
   _BindingSource.DataSource = dSource; 
   // hack - refresh binding list
3. **Enjoy :)**

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I was using a form to create rows in my table without saving the context each time. Luckily I had multiple forms doing this and one updated the grid properly and one didn't.

The only difference?
I bound one to the entity similarly (not using the bindingSource) to what you did:

```
myGrid.DataSource = myDataContext.MyTable;
```

The second I bound:

```
myGrid.DataSource = myDataContext.MyTable.ToList();
```

The second way worked.

Answer (score 1):

Grid Data Source Referesh by new query instead just Contest.Table.
Simple Solution < But Working.

Whre is eg. 
!!!!! Thanks - Problem Solved after no of days !!! but with so simple way ..

```
CrmDemoContext.CrmDemoDataContext Context = new CrmDemoContext.CrmDemoDataContext();

var query = from it in Context.Companies select it;
// initial connection
dataGridView1.DataSource = query;
```

after changes or add in data

```
Context.SubmitChanges();
//call here again 
dataGridView1.DataSource = query;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should also refresh/update datagrid. You need to force redraw of grid.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you insert rows. I had same problem when used `DataContext.InsertOnSubmit(row)`, but when I just inserted rows into BindingSource instead `BindingSource.Insert(Bindingsource.Count, row)`
and used DataContext only to `DataContext.SubmitChanges()` and `DataContext.GetChangeSet()`. BindingSource inserts rows into both grid and context.

Answer (score 0):

> the answer from **Atomosk** helped me to solve a similar problem -
>   thanks a lot **Atomosk**!

I updated my database by the following two lines of code, but the DataGridView did not show the changes (it did not add a new row):

```
this.dataContext.MyTable.InsertOnSubmit(newDataset);
this.dataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

Where *this.dataContext.MyTable* was set to the *DataSource* property of a *BindingSource* object, which was set to the *DataSource* property of a *DataGridView* object.
In code it does looks like this:

```
DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = this.dataContext.MyTable; // Table<T> object type
dgv.DataSource = bs;
```

Setting *bs.DataSource* equals *null* and after that back to *this.dataContext.MyTable* did not help to update the DataGridView either.

The only way to update the DataGridView with the new entry was a complete different approach by adding it to the BindingSource instead of the corresponding table of the DataContext, as **Atomosk** mentioned.

```
this.bs.Add(newDataset);
this.dataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

Without doing so `bs.Count;` returned a smaller number as `this.dataContext.MyTable.Count();`
This does not make sense and seems to be a bug in the binding model in my opinion.